# Leave message to Drupal 7 with iPhone app

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How to leave message to an article in Drupal 7 with iPhone app (iOS 4.3)? Any connector from D7 I can use in iOS SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Drupal Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) provides endpoints via XMLRPC/JSON-RPC/etc. to perform many core functions remotely (including adding comments to nodes). As far as I know that's currently the only option available without having to write a connector yourself.